# Can't get .table-striped class to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't get my table-stripe class to work with my Bootstrap framework.

Here's a live preview of my table. I have the .table-striped class set in my HTML, but it's not showing on the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I see stipes?

Comment: That's because I got it fixed:) Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, it's better to post code samples rather than a link to a live site which is likely to change in the future, making this question less useful to others.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Adding my code here since I had same problem but didn't have code to look at in the question.
`lang-html
<table class="table table-striped" id="process-monitor-data"><br />
    <tr><br />
        <th>Process <br />Index</th><br />
        .......<br />
        </tr><br />
        <tr v-for="item in ProcessMonitorData" v-if="IsRowVisible(item)" :item="item"><br />
        <td>{{item.ProcessMonitorIndex}}</td><br />
        ...<br />
        </tr><br />
    </table>`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your html is wrong. You have a `tbody` tag for each row but the css for `.table-striped` relies on `tr:nth-child()` to style the rows differently:

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th
```

Fix your html so that you have a single tbody to iterate through.

Also, I saw both the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css in your resources. One is enough.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your table markup. You have each row wrappped in a tbody tag and according to the bootstrap documentation:

> Adds zebra-striping to any table row within the  via the :nth-child CSS selector (not available in IE7-8).

So if you go through and remove all the tbody tags so that there is just one at the beginning of your table body and one at the end, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional information, the ng-repeat should be on:

> ```
> <tr> inside <tbody>:
> ```

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1"></th>
            <th class="col-md-5"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="v1 in v">
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"/></td>
            <td>{{v1.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be thead tag and tbody tag should be there to work "table-striped", without those tags striped style won't get applied to the table.
Here's the example:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><mark>#Periods</mark></th>
            <th><mark>Monday</mark></th>
            <th><mark>Tuesday</mark></th>
            <th><mark>Wednesday</mark></th>
            <th><mark>Thursday</mark></th>
            <th><mark>Friday</mark></th>
            <th><mark>Saturday</mark></th>
            <th><mark>Sunday</mark></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>MATHS</td>
            <td>ENGLISH</td>
            <td>PHYSICS</td>
            <td>SOCIAL</td>
            <td>SCIENCE</td>
            <td>TELUGU</td>
            <td>HOLIDAY</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>MATHS</td>
            <td>SCIENCE</td>
            <td>PHYSICS</td>
            <td>SOCIAL</td>
            <td>TELUGU</td>
            <td>ENGLISH</td>
            <td>HOLIDAY</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```